# Javascript check if a variable is the window

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

do you know a good way to check if a variable is the window object in javascript?
I tried with:

```
var variable=window;
Object.prototype.toString.call(variable);
```

In Firefox it returns `"[object Window]"` but in IE `"[object Object]"` so that's not the right way. Do you know an accurate way to check it?

Comment: Can you just do an equivalence test against `window` ? `(somevar === window)?'yes':'no'`

Comment: But if it's an iframe window it won't work.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need to do this?

Comment: IE11 returns [object Window]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *Yes but i need a way to check every window not only the current one*

There are a few ways you can do this.  The simplest method is to check for one or two known properties on the window object.  There's also the `self` property - for each window, you could check the `self` property is equal to the window object:

```
myvar.self == myvar;
window.self == window;
frameElement.contentWindow.self == frameElement.contentWindow;
```

Comment: `self` can be overwritten and is often used as a variable name to retain context.

Comment: @zzzzBov: So, what?  Most properties can be overwritten, but you would rarely see this happen when trying to *"retain context"* because it doesn't occur in the global scope and any self respecting developer would declare with `var` anywhere else.  As long as you refer to `window.self` and not just `self`, you should be OK.  If it matters that much to anyone, I suppose they could use `window.window` rather than `window.self`, if they want.  It's protected from being overwritten in most modern browsers.

Comment: @AndyE, I am simply trying to find a more resilient means of checking if an object is a `window` in an academic sense. For example, `o = {}; o.self = o; isWindow(o)` would return true in your version. `jQuery` checks if `setInterval` is set, so `$.isWindow({setInterval:1})` returns incorrectly.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I don't believe there is one.  The jQuery developers probably chose `setInterval` because it's least likely to be re-used as a property name on another object and it's supported by all known browsers.  A modern alternative might be to use `Object.prototype.toString(obj)`, which would return `[object global]` or `[object Window]` in most browsers, with the major exceptions being IE 7 and lower.  Still not fully resilient, though.  Maybe in 5 years.

Comment: @AndyE, I've already added an answer to this question which I *think* is resilient. It needs more testing for edge cases.

Comment: @zzzz: oops, I didn't realize. I guess you figured the `Object.prototype.toString` stuff out by yourself, then :-)

Answer (score 5):

Found this in AngularJS source code. A one liner and bang on target.

```
return variable && variable.document && variable.location && variable.alert && variable.setInterval;
```

Comment: When variable is undefined this will throw exception (as function returns undefined instead of true/false):  instanceof Window is best simple method to check.  To use this AngularJS code, wrap it in try{}catch or with (typeof variable !== 'undefined')

Comment: This returns the setInterval function, if it exists. Adding an `&& true` to the end would fix this.

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
isWindow = variable === window;
```

The triple-equals prevents type coercion that otherwise would make this much harder to do.

Comment: Yes but i need a way to check every window not only the current one.

Comment: The type-strict check isn't necessary when comparing the same object.

Answer (score 1):

After toying around with many options, I believe this is the most accurate method for detecting if an object is a window cross-browser:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var wStr;
    wStr = Object.prototype.toString.call(window);
    function isWindow(arg) {
        var e,
            str,
            self,
            hasSelf;
        //Safari returns DOMWindow
        //Chrome returns global
        //Firefox, Opera & IE9 return Window
        str = Object.prototype.toString.call(arg);
        switch (wStr) {
        case '[object DOMWindow]':
        case '[object Window]':
        case '[object global]':
            return str === wStr;
        }
        ///window objects always have a `self` property;
        ///however, `arg.self == arg` could be fooled by:
        ///var o = {};
        ///o.self = o;
        if ('self' in arg) {
            //`'self' in arg` is true if
            //the property exists on the object _or_ the prototype
            //`arg.hasOwnProperty('self')` is true only if
            //the property exists on the object
            hasSelf = arg.hasOwnProperty('self');
            try {
                if (hasSelf) {
                    self = arg.self;
                }
                delete arg.self;
                if (hasSelf) {
                    arg.self = self;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                //IE 7&8 throw an error when window.self is deleted
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}());
```

I will need to perform some more rigorous unit-testing, so ***please*** let me know of any inconsistencies that arise.

Comment: I've updated your answer because there was an error, then i've tested it and it seems to work, but i think that the first part is too restrictive because almost every browser has its own way to convert the window to string and maybe there are more than 3 variants.

Comment: @mck89, I'm primarily concerned with the big 5: Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE. It would be awfully nice if browsers normalized to using `'[object Window]'`, however the ECMAScript5 spec [allows each browser to choose its own value for the `[[Class]]` property of the global object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1). In that sense, yes, it is a relatively restrictive implementation, however I think it's much more resilient than checking `arg.self == arg`, which is easily fooled.

Comment: I really do commend your effort, but I wonder who needs to be this strict. Perhaps a library would make use of it, but even jQuery thinks `if (obj && typeof obj === "object" && "setInterval" in obj)` is adequate enough. When is there ever a need for someone to write `o.self = o`, and how likely is it that someone is going to need to check that it's a `window` object?  As for resilience, your use of `"use strict"` makes the function even less resilient than `arg.self === arg` because a *TypeError* will be thrown when you delete a `self` property with the `Configurable` attribute set to `false`.

Comment: @AndyE, as I mentioned in a previous comment, I'm curious in an academic sense. I've set myself a challenge of writing a (mostly) foolproof `isWindow` function. Obviously overriding `Object.prototype.toString`, or `Function.prototype.call` would give incorrect results, but I'd ideally like a function that can correctly identify a window object accurately.

Comment: @zzzzBov: well, I sure can understand that. Yesterday when you commented on my answer I had a quick look at the `Object.prototype.toString` stuff and noticed that `window.constructor.prototype.toString !== Object.prototype.toString` in all the major browsers. I spent the next 2 hours trying to figure out why and I still don't know the answer. Some things just get you like that.

Comment: @AndyE, most native objects have overridden `toString` in their prototypes; for example, chrome reports `window.constructor` as `function DOMWindow() {...}`. Which has a different prototype from `Object`. Unfortunately checking `arg.toString()` is even less consistent than `Object.prototype.toString.call(arg)` and more prone to errors, as I could easily see someone defining a custom `Window` object with a custom `toString` that returns `[object Window]` or similar. Fortunately, I rarely have a true need for actual type checking in JS.

Comment: @zzzzBov: in Chrome, Firefox and IE 9+, `DOMWindow` / `Window` inherits properties and methods from `Object` through the prototype chain. Included in the inheritance is `toLocaleString()`, which does much the same as `toString()`.  I was confused as to why `toString()` is not inherited even though the result is the same (except in Chrome, which returns *"[object DOMWindow]"* for `window.toString()`, rather than *"[object global]"*).

Answer (score 0):

```
variable == window
```

Someone could still define a local variable called `window`.  I'm not sure there's a way that's resilient to all such shenanigans.  Someone could make an object that copied most of the window properties and functions, including `toString`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(variable == window)
```

That of course only checks if the variable object is this window (i.e. the window of the document executing the javascript).

Alternatively, you could try something like this:

```
if(variable.document && variable.location)
```

And check for the existance of a few window fields and/or functions so you are *pretty sure* that it is a window...

Answer (score 0):

1. The `window` object has a property that points to itself. So you can use, `window.window == window`.
2. `this` always holds the current context. You can use, `this == window`.
3. In case if multiple `frame`s present, every frame contains its own `window` object. To check for global `window` object, you can use `window.parent == window`

```js
console.log("1 : " + (window.window == window))
console.log("2 : " + (window.window == this))
console.log("3 : " + (window.parent == window))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are "almost" all checks you can perform to your window(w):

- If you're checking an object to be a `window` in any context, this should do

```js
// the `false` branch is for `boolean` TypeScript consistency and tests
const isWindow = (object) => object && object.constructor.name === 'Window' || false;


isWindow() // => false
isWindow(window) // => true
isWindow(window.parent) // => true
isWindow(window.top) // => true
```

The reason behind this kind of check is that test runners run into all kinds of problems with native methods called within various iframes, especially `instanceof`.

- If you want to check if your window is the TOP / PARENT / CONTEXT / ONE

```js
const win = window;

// TOP
console.log(win === win.top)

// PARENT
console.log(win === win.parent)

// CONTEXT
console.log(win === win.self)

// ONE WINDOW
console.log(win === win.self && win === win.top)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Since `window` is a global variable and global variables are properties of the global object, `window.window` will equal `window`. So you could test:

```
if (mysteryVariable.window == mysteryVariable)
    ...
```

The problem is that this can be fooled if we have an object like this:

```
var q = {};
q.window = q;
```

If that's not likely, then you can use this code.

Answer (score -1):

```
let isWindowObj = (anObject instanceof Window);
```